# What is the word in English getting things after lots of struggle?

Tags: idioms, proverbs

What is the word in English getting things after lots of struggle?

In psychology there is a theory that, people give more importance to the things which they get after lots of struggle and effort. When they get it easily, they do not know the importance of it. What is the English word for the same ?

Comment: Sense of achievement :  a proud feeling of having done something difficult and worthwhile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [*hard-earned*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hard-earned) will fit your description:

> achieved or acquired through a lot of effort or hard work
>
> - Someone stole all her hard-earned money.
> - a hard-earned victory

<sub>(Merriam-Webster)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

One idiom is [*to triumph over adversity*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/triumph):

> **triumph** noun [ C or U ]
>   ​
>   a very great success, achievement, or victory (= when you win a war, fight, or competition), or a feeling of great satisfaction or pleasure caused by this:
>
> - The book celebrates the hostages' remarkable triumph over appalling adversity.

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [arduous](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/arduous) is the word you are looking for:

> ar•du•ous /ˈɑrdʒuəs/
>
> 1 - requiring great energy or exertion.
>
> 2 - full of hardship;severe.

Example:

> "The arduous journey into the center of the great desert began."